# How to get all metrics for a SageMaker Hyperparameter tuning job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

SageMaker does offer a HyperparameterTuningJobAnalytics object, but it only contains the final objective metric value.

Here is example code.

```py
tuner = sagemaker.HyperparameterTuningJobAnalytics(tuning_job_name)

full_df = tuner.dataframe()
```

The dataframe it returns only contains the objective metric as the column FinalObjectiveValue.

If I have defined more than one metric for the tuning job, how do I get other metrics in SageMaker?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all metrics you have configured for your job using `describe_training_job`. Here is an example using boto3:

Create the SageMaker client:

```
smclient = boto3.client('sagemaker')
```

Get a list of all training jobs (note the example parameters here - only getting the last 100 jobs sorted by the final objective metric in descending order):

```
trjobs = smclient.list_training_jobs_for_hyper_parameter_tuning_job(
    HyperParameterTuningJobName='YOUR_TUNING_JOB_NAME_HERE',
    MaxResults=100,
    SortBy='FinalObjectiveMetricValue',
    SortOrder='Descending')
```

Iterate over each job summary and retrieve all metrics:

```
for trjob in trjobs['TrainingJobSummaries']:
    jobd = smclient.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=trjob['TrainingJobName'])
    metrics = {m['MetricName']:  m['Value'] for m in jobd['FinalMetricDataList']}
    print '%s Metrics: %s' % (trjob['TrainingJobName'], metrics)
```